# iOS Create TabController without storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, xib

maybe stupid, but i'm in confuse, cant find any example creating UITabBarController without storyboard.

I have simply single view application. And then i press button i want presentViewController which is UITabBarController

My xib UITabBarController looks like
[image]

as u can see i have two TabBarItems, but then i run it's on simulator i got this picture

[image]

Here interface of My tab bar controller

```
@interface TabsViewController : UITabBarController
```

and i show its

```
 TabsViewController *tb = [[TabsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabsViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:tb animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also i don't want create it's by code, i want use xib.

Answer (score 0):

In your .h ViewController file import the tab menu:

```
#import “TabMenu”
@interface firstVC : UIViewController
{
    TabMenu *customView;
}
```

In your .m ViewController file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    customView = [TabMenu tabMenu];

    [customView setFrame:CGRectMake(-customView.frame.size.width, customView.frame.origin.y, customView.frame.size.width, customView.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:customView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

In your TabMenu.h

```
+ (id)tabMenu;
```

In your TabMenu.m add this function

```
+ (id)tabMenu {
    TabMenu *customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@“TabMenu” owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    // make sure customView is not nil or the wrong class!
    if ([customView isKindOfClass:[TabMenu class]])
        return customView;
    else
        return nil;
}
```